# Selecting specific rows from an array when a condition is met in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of IoU values with 300 rows and 4 columns. A row is selected if every element in that row is less than 0.5. I wrote a code which try to do this but it returns rows in which every element is zero.

```
import numpy as np
iou = np.random.rand(300,4)

negative_boxes = []
for x in range(len(iou)):
    if iou[x,:].any() < 0.5:
       negative_boxes.append(iou[x])
```

How to select rows in which every element is less than 0.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `for` loop, you can use numpy masks, that are more efficient.

With your problem:

```
import numpy as np
iou = np.random.rand(300,4)
indices = np.where((iou < 0.5).all(axis=1))
negative_boxes = iou[indices]
```

Then `indices` contains all the indices of the rows where all values are smaller than 0.5 and `negative_boxes` contains the array with only the small values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`a.any()` returns `True` if any of the elements of `a` evaluate to `True`, `False` otherwise.

`if iou[x,:].any() < 0.5` implicitly converts the boolean value returned by `iou[x,:].any()` to 0 and 1 (in fact, `bool` is a subclass of `int`). Thus `iou[x,:].any() < 0.5` is `True` if and only if `iou[x,:].any()` is False, i.e., every element of `iou[x,:]` is 0.

To check if all elements of an array `a` are less than 0.5, use `np.all`:

```
import numpy as np
iou = np.random.rand(300,4)

negative_boxes = []
for x in range(len(iou)):
    if np.all(iou[x, :] < 0.5):
       negative_boxes.append(iou[x])
```